# Airflow CLI to pause, resume and stop an executing DAG

Tags: airflow

My application design requires that an Airflow DAG, which is currently being executed, can be paused if executing, resume if paused and stopped. This is different from the pause/unpause functionality provided. For example, if a DAG has 8 components and 3 components have already executed successfully. Now I want to pause the execution of this DAG. After some time, I want to resume that paused DAG. After 6 components, I realised that this DAG has a major flaw and I need to terminate its execution.

I tried to look for these three functionalities in the [CLI documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html) but could not find these functions. [API documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/api.html) also does not tell about any API which can do this.

Would request Airflow veterans to suggest on this.

Comment: The Pause/Unpause functionality exactly does that. Why do you think this is a different feature?

https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#pause

Comment: The pause functionality as given in Airflow means no further DAG triggers would execute the DAG. The current DAG run is not affected if we pause (the same functionality shipped with airflow) in between. That's why I mentioned "This is different from the pause/unpause functionality provided" above. What exactly I am looking for is a method to pause an ongoing DAG run. And another method to further resume it or terminate / stop it.

Comment: did you give it a try, it should complete running the current task and pause from the next task for the current DAG Run as well.

Comment: Yes. It however did not pause the ongoing run. Only it prevented subsequent trigger ed runs.

Comment: I will need to check then. Will update here after checking

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63619924/3679900) is identical; [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55908676/3679900) is related; unfortunately those also don't have a solution yet

Answer (score 0):

Using `airflow cheat-sheet`, in Airflow `2.3.3`, one gets:

```bash
Miscellaneous commands                                                                               
airflow cheat-sheet                       | Display cheat sheet                                      
airflow dag-processor                     | Start a standalone Dag Processor instance                
airflow info                              | Show information about current Airflow and environment   
airflow kerberos                          | Start a kerberos ticket renewer                          
airflow plugins                           | Dump information about loaded plugins                    
airflow rotate-fernet-key                 | Rotate encrypted connection credentials and variables    
airflow scheduler                         | Start a scheduler instance                               
airflow standalone                        | Run an all-in-one copy of Airflow                        
airflow sync-perm                         | Update permissions for existing roles and optionally DAGs
airflow triggerer                         | Start a triggerer instance                               
airflow version                           | Show the version                                         
airflow webserver                         | Start a Airflow webserver instance                       
                                                                                                     
Celery components                                                            
airflow celery flower                     | Start a Celery Flower            
airflow celery stop                       | Stop the Celery worker gracefully
airflow celery worker                     | Start a Celery worker node       
                                                                             
View configuration                                                              
airflow config get-value                  | Print the value of the configuration
airflow config list                       | List options for the configuration  
                                                                                
Manage connections                                                        
airflow connections add                   | Add a connection              
airflow connections delete                | Delete a connection           
airflow connections export                | Export all connections        
airflow connections get                   | Get a connection              
airflow connections import                | Import connections from a file
airflow connections list                  | List connections              
                                                                          
Manage DAGs                                                                                    
airflow dags backfill                     | Run subsections of a DAG for a specified date range
airflow dags delete                       | Delete all DB records related to the specified DAG 
airflow dags list                         | List all the DAGs                                  
airflow dags list-import-errors           | List all the DAGs that have import errors          
airflow dags list-jobs                    | List the jobs                                      
airflow dags list-runs                    | List DAG runs given a DAG id                       
airflow dags next-execution               | Get the next execution datetimes of a DAG          
airflow dags pause                        | Pause a DAG                                        
airflow dags report                       | Show DagBag loading report                         
airflow dags reserialize                  | Reserialize all DAGs by parsing the DagBag files   
airflow dags show                         | Displays DAG's tasks with their dependencies       
airflow dags show-dependencies            | Displays DAGs with their dependencies              
airflow dags state                        | Get the status of a dag run                        
airflow dags test                         | Execute one single DagRun                          
airflow dags trigger                      | Trigger a DAG run                                  
airflow dags unpause                      | Resume a paused DAG                                
                                                                                               
Database operations                                                                        
airflow db check                          | Check if the database can be reached           
airflow db check-migrations               | Check if migration have finished               
airflow db clean                          | Purge old records in metastore tables          
airflow db downgrade                      | Downgrade the schema of the metadata database. 
airflow db init                           | Initialize the metadata database               
airflow db reset                          | Burn down and rebuild the metadata database    
airflow db shell                          | Runs a shell to access the database            
airflow db upgrade                        | Upgrade the metadata database to latest version
                                                                                           
Manage jobs                                                                 
airflow jobs check                        | Checks if job(s) are still alive
                                                                            
Tools to help run the KubernetesExecutor                                                                                                                             
airflow kubernetes cleanup-pods           | Clean up Kubernetes pods (created by KubernetesExecutor/KubernetesPodOperator) in evicted/failed/succeeded/pending states
airflow kubernetes generate-dag-yaml      | Generate YAML files for all tasks in DAG. Useful for debugging tasks without launching into a cluster                    
                                                                                                                                                                     
Manage pools                                                
airflow pools delete                      | Delete pool     
airflow pools export                      | Export all pools
airflow pools get                         | Get pool size   
airflow pools import                      | Import pools    
airflow pools list                        | List pools      
airflow pools set                         | Configure pool  
                                                            
Display providers                                                                                                   
airflow providers auth                    | Get information about API auth backends provided                        
airflow providers behaviours              | Get information about registered connection types with custom behaviours
airflow providers get                     | Get detailed information about a provider                               
airflow providers hooks                   | List registered provider hooks                                          
airflow providers links                   | List extra links registered by the providers                            
airflow providers list                    | List installed providers                                                
airflow providers logging                 | Get information about task logging handlers provided                    
airflow providers secrets                 | Get information about secrets backends provided                         
airflow providers widgets                 | Get information about registered connection form widgets                
                                                                                                                    
Manage roles                                                                                       
airflow roles create                      | Create role                                            
airflow roles export                      | Export roles (without permissions) from db to JSON file
airflow roles import                      | Import roles (without permissions) from JSON file to db
airflow roles list                        | List roles                                             
                                                                                                   
Manage tasks                                                                                  
airflow tasks clear                       | Clear a set of task instance, as if they never ran
airflow tasks failed-deps                 | Returns the unmet dependencies for a task instance
airflow tasks list                        | List the tasks within a DAG                       
airflow tasks render                      | Render a task instance's template(s)              
airflow tasks run                         | Run a single task instance                        
airflow tasks state                       | Get the status of a task instance                 
airflow tasks states-for-dag-run          | Get the status of all task instances in a dag run 
airflow tasks test                        | Test a task instance                              
                                                                                              
Manage users                                                       
airflow users add-role                    | Add role to a user     
airflow users create                      | Create a user          
airflow users delete                      | Delete a user          
airflow users export                      | Export all users       
airflow users import                      | Import users           
airflow users list                        | List users             
airflow users remove-role                 | Remove role from a user
                                                                   
Manage variables                                                
airflow variables delete                  | Delete variable     
airflow variables export                  | Export all variables
airflow variables get                     | Get variable        
airflow variables import                  | Import variables    
airflow variables list                    | List variables      
airflow variables set                     | Set variable
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could note the version of Airflow that these commands relate to, as they have changed over time

Answer (score 0):

To pause:

```
airflow dags pause <your_dag_id_here>
```

unpause:

```
airflow dags unpause <your_dag_id_here>
```

delete:

```
yes | airflow dags delete <your_dag_id_here>
```

Btw, if inside a dag... you can use a BashOperator as in:

```
BashOperator(
        task_id="delete_dags",
        bash_command="airflow dags list -o plain | grep -o '^\S*' | xargs -L1 -t airflow dags delete -y",
    )
```