# Airflow - pause/unpause individual dagruns of the same DAG running in parallel

Tags: airflow

We are currently evaluating airflow for a project. I was wondering if there is a way to stop/start individual dagruns while running a DAG multiple times in parallel. Pause/unpause on dag_id seems to pause/unpause all the dagruns under a dag. Instead we want to pause individual dagruns (or tasks within them). Let me know if this is achievable in airflow.

If its not possible, here are other alternatives I am thinking of, let me know your opinion on these

1. Change task state. – Change all tasks under a dagrun to Mark Failed or Success. That way that particular dagrun is stopped on its tracks without affecting other dagruns.
2. Airflow sensor to pull    this information from s3 or http or sql or somewhere to pause    current dagrun. And have a task to check on s3 everytime if this    dagrun needs to be stopped (not other dagruns).
3. subdags. - Can we    pause/unpause subdags. That way for each parallel user's request we want to do we issue a subdag and we can pause userAs subdag without impacting other user’s subdags.

Comment: this question has been asked [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55908676/3679900) but I doubt there's a native solution yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing "baked" into Airflow to support this but you could (ab)use the state of the `DagRun` by changing it to `"failed"` to pause and then back to `"running"` to resume; you won't be able to blanket unpause but for testing it should be workable.

Comment: Thanks @joebeeson. Do you know if there is a way to mark the dagrun as "failed" through REST API or CLI? I saw there is "airflow run" that allows us to mark a task "succeeded" but didnt see anyway to market a task or dagrun "failed".

Comment: After some digging, I was able to update the row in task_instance table with 'failed' state for that execution_date which seems to reflect in the UI fine for that task under that specific dagrun. Couldnt find that option in CLI. However, I was able to run that task from CLI ignoring all dependencies (option -A).